# No tests found for given includes Error for Cucumber+TestNG project in Gradle but not in Maven

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber, testng

I have been trying to create a barebones Cucumber TestNG project in Gradle, but it consistently fails to run any tests, returning the error `No tests found for given includes`. Trying to create an identical project in Maven lets the tests run perfectly fine. Is there some a problem with Gradle and the `cucumber-testng` dependency? Has anyone else encountered this problem? I am using IntelliJ IDEA to run tests in both case.

Comment: Do you face the same error when running tests from command line outside IDE?